# How to compile each jasper file to its own directory?

Tags: ant, jasper-reports

I'm trying to create a ant script to compile my jasper files, but I have many "srcdir" and "destdir":

```
<target name="all"> 
  <jrc
    srcdir="many..."
    destdir="many..."
    tempdir="any"
    xmlvalidation="true">
   <classpath refid="classpath"/>
   <include name="**/*.jrxml"/>
  </jrc>
</target>
```

...and I would like it to compile each file to it's own dir. For every ".jrxml" file.

Is there a way?

Comment: Could you provide an example of values for different `srcdir` and `destdir`? I think the [`foreach`](http://ant-contrib.sourceforge.net/tasks/tasks/foreach.html) ant-contrib task is what you want here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use ant-contrib [`foreach`](http://ant-contrib.sourceforge.net/tasks/tasks/foreach.html) task to loop over each `jrxml` file and call the `jrc` task for each of those. If you don't have it, you'll need to [install ant-contrib](http://ant-contrib.sourceforge.net/) by copying its JAR file to the `lib` directory of your Ant installation (if you're using Eclipse, you can add it by going to "Window > Preferences > Ant > Runtime" and adding the JAR into "Ant Home Entries").

The following defines a target `"all"` that will select all the `jrxml` files under the current directory. For each of those file, the `"jrc"` target will be called and the corresponding file will be referenced by the property `jrxml.file`.

Inside this task, the directory where the `jrxml` file is located is retrieved with the [`dirname`](https://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/dirname.html) task and the name of the `jrxml` file is retrieved with the [`basename`](https://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/basename.html) task. The built `.jasper` file will be created under a folder having the same name as the `jrxml` file. (It needs to be created first with the [`mkdir`](https://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/mkdir.html) task).

```
<taskdef resource="net/sf/antcontrib/antcontrib.properties" />

<target name="all"> 
  <foreach target="jrc" param="jrxml.file">
    <path>
      <fileset dir=".">
        <include name="**/*.jrxml"/>
      </fileset>
    </path>
  </foreach>
</target>

<target name="jrc">
  <dirname property="jrxml.dir" file="${jrxml.file}"/>
  <basename property="jrxml.filename" file="${jrxml.file}" suffix="jrxml"/>
  <mkdir dir="${jrxml.dir}/${jrxml.filename}"/>
  <jrc srcdir="${jrxml.dir}"
       destdir="${jrxml.dir}/${jrxml.filename}"
       tempdir="${jrxml.dir}/${jrxml.filename}"
       xmlvalidation="true">
    <classpath refid="classpath"/>
    <include name="${jrxml.filename}.jrxml"/>
  </jrc>
</target>
```

As an example, if you have a structure:

```
+folder
+--jrxml
+----Example1.jrxml
+----Example2.jrxml
```

the result will be

```
+folder
+--jrxml
+----Example1.jrxml
+----Example1
+------Example1.jasper
+----Example2.jrxml
+----Example2
+------Example2.jasper
```